# Global routing between angular modules

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using Angular2 in my project and I have several modules.

I have base module which is called `BaseModule`
And have for example two (or more) extra modules - `FirstModule` and `SecondModule`.

Each module has his own routing. `BaseModule` has basic routes for system, 
`FirstModule` and `SecondModule` has his own separated routes.

BUT

I want to create routes like

`/user/10/profile`

Where `ProfileComponent` for user contains into `FirstModule`

Another examples

`/user/10/stories`

Where `StoriesComponent` for user contains into `FirstModule`

`/user/10/news`

Where `NewsComponent` for user contains into `SecondModule`!!!!

But Angular Router allow only routes like:

`/firstmodule/......`

`/secondmodule/......`

So, they should be grouped by module.

I want to do it with modules because I want to have async(lazy) loaded parts of my application.

As I know Angular disallow variants when we async(lazy) load components.

Anybody have ideas how I can create what I want?

Answer (score 0):

For routes in root module define your roots as `RouterModule.forRoot([''])` and for routes in the other modules use `RouterModule.forChild([''])`. Since your child modules will be in the `imports` of the parent this will route properly.